# Resolving symbols in a Common Lisp list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, symbols, evaluation

Suppose I have a function

```
CL-USER> (defun trimmer (seq) "This trims seq and returns a list"
      (cdr 
         (butlast seq)))
TRIMMER
CL-USER> (trimmer '(1 2 3 VAR1 VAR2))
(2 3 VAR1)
CL-USER>
```

Notice how, due to QUOTE, VAR1 and VAR2 are not resolved. Suppose I want to resolve the symbols VAR1 and VAR2 to their values - is there a standard function to do this?

Comment: And what is the problem with using `list` instead of `quote`?

Comment: what does 'resolve' mean in the context of Lisp? The primitive operation in Lisp to compute a value is called evaluation.

Answer (score 6):

Do not use `quote` to create a list with variables; use `list` instead:

```
CL-USER> (trimmer (list 1 2 3 var1 var2))
(2 3 value-of-var1)
```

(where `value-of-var1` is the value of `var1`).

`Quote` only prevents evaluation of whatever its argument is.  If its argument happens to be a list literal, then that is returned.  However, to create lists that are not just literals, use `list`.  You *can* use backquote syntax, but that is rather obfuscation in such a case.

Answer (score 4):

[Backquote](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/sec_2-4-6.html) is the usual way to interpolate values into a quoted list:

```
> (setq var1 4 var2 5)
5
> `(1 2 3 ,var1 ,var2)
(1 2 3 4 5)
```

Edited to add: if you want to process a list so that symbols are replaced with their [`symbol-value`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_symb_5.htm), then you need a function something like this:

```
(defun interpolate-symbol-values (list)
  "Return a copy of LIST with symbols replaced by their symbol-value."
  (loop for x in list
        collect (if (symbolp x) (symbol-value x) x)))

> (interpolate-variables '(1 2 3 var1 var2))
(1 2 3 4 5)
```

This seems like a strange thing to want to do, however. Can you say more about what you are trying to achieve? Almost certainly there's a better way to do it than this.

Comment: I don't know how many non-resolved variables there might be in the list.

Comment: How come? In your problem description you mention using `QUOTE`. If you can use `QUOTE` you can use backquote, surely? (Maybe you need to describe your problem a bit more explicitly.)

Comment: @Gareth: I was using quote to ensure that the first argument wasn't evaluated as a function.

Comment: Yes, but backquote avoids function application too. I don't yet see why you can do one but not the other.

Comment: @Gareth - I've generally used quote to avoid list application. I don't know that I have a particular reason.

Comment: @Paul Nathan:  The quote signals "the following syntax unit is literal data" and if that happens to be a list, then the whole list is "literal data". If you're building a list from variables, either use backquote (with commas to unquote what you want to be evaluated) or use the standard funtion list to build a list with some or all emelents evaluated in the calling environment.